# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables for Docker host

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I have an EB env with Docker web app (rails) properly deployed. I set several EB env variables and they are properly visible in the container. Now - I'd like these EB env variables to be visible to the EC2 instance host, so that I can use them in the docker build process. However, they are not exposed to the docker host, only to the container.
**How do I expose EB env variables to the Docker host?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a though one, so I'm posting my solution for those who encounter this.
Elastic Beanstalk Docker instance does not expose the environment variables to the docker host. It does that only to the docker container.
If you'd like to get the env variables on the host, they are located at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration`.
This is one large JSON file, *conveniently* disobeying the JSON structure for the env vars.
I wrote a small ruby script to parse it and extract the env vars from it:

```
require 'json'
container_config = JSON.parse(File.read('/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration'))
raw_vars =  container_config['optionsettings']['aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment']
envs = ''
raw_vars.each do |raw_var|
  pair = raw_var.split('=')
  envs << "export #{pair[0]}=#{pair[1]}\n" if pair[1]
end
puts envs
```

this script yields a set of export commands to console that sets the env vars. I adapted it a bit to write `ENV` commands into my `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Could you share how you managed to get them as ENV commands inside the Dockerfile?

Comment: @GlendGjermeni you set the ENV variables as elastic beanstalk environment variables (I did it from the web console manually). These are propagated to the docker container. It's a different approach than using a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue, but needed the environment variables to be available during the execution of a post-deployment Bash script.

Since the [jq parser](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is available on the (current) Amazon Linux AMIs, I was able to acheive something similar using it to parse the JSON and then export the environment variables on the host (this is an excerpt from an [ebextensions config file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)):

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/export_env_vars_on_host.sh":
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
    for envvar in `jq '.optionsettings | {"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"}[] | .[]' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration`
    do
      temp="${envvar#\"}";
      temp="${temp/=/=\"}";
      export temp;
    done
```

Comment: I encountered a problem with this, having used this for a while. If you have a environment variable with a space inside it will not work. E.g. TEST_VAR="x y z". Is there a easy fix to this ?

Comment: I figured that you must add `IFS=$'\n'` before the for loop. So for loop does not use space as separator.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested this on all versions of Elasticbeanstalk. But on at least 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running Multi-container Docker 1.6.2 (Generic) there's a nicer way to get the envars from your config. There's a ruby script on the instance already that provides a proper json representation of the envars `{ "SOME_ENV_VAT" : "VALUE" }`

```
# returns literal null from jq
sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MY_ENVVAR'

# returns empty string. Usefull for bash -z
sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MY_ENVVAR // empty'
```

Answer (score 2):

King of the one liners.

```
eval $(sudo ruby -e 'require "json"; container_config = JSON.parse(File.read("/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration")); raw_vars = container_config["optionsettings"]["aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"]; envs = ""; raw_vars.each do |raw_var| envs << "export #{raw_var};\n" end; print envs;')
```

This will automatically export all the variables. You cannot use `puts` to output environment variables with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Patrick H McJury's answer.

Here is how it worked for me in a multi container beanstalk environment -

**.ebextensions/newrelic.config** -

```
container_commands:
  setup-nr-infra:
    command: |
      NRIA_LICENSE_KEY=$(sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY')
      NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME=$(sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.APPNAME')
      touch /etc/newrelic-infra.yml && \
      echo "license_key: ${NRIA_LICENSE_KEY}" > /etc/newrelic-infra.yml && \
      echo "display_name: ${NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME}" >> /etc/newrelic-infra.yml && \
      chmod 644 /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
      sudo initctl start newrelic-infra || true

commands:
# Create the agent’s yum repository
  "01-agent-repository":
    command: sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/newrelic-infra.repo https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/6/x86_64/newrelic-infra.repo
#
# Update your yum cache
  "02-update-yum-cache":
    command: yum -q makecache -y --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='newrelic-infra'
#
# Run the installation script
  "03-run-installation-script":
    command: sudo yum install newrelic-infra -y
```

`NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY` & `APPNAME` variable must be populated before in beanstalk environment.